# Fixed Position div Vertical Only

Tags: jquery, css, position, horizontal-scrolling, css-position

I have a current web build with a right sidebar that is a fixed position. I have tried to positioning from the right but don't want it overlapping other divs content.

What I am looking for is to have the content scrollable horizontally to the right when it is out of the viewport window. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

similarly to this: http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/ however I can not get this working.

---

This has been solved by alternative method. Thanks for those who actually considered helping.

Comment: Your demo page shows three different things.  Which one are you looking to do?

Comment: It's a fixed position div... why do you have a `float:left;` in there?

Answer (score 22):

Keep the fixed div.

And have the following javascript code which will take care of horizontal moving.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.fixed_div').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: Great answer. Was looking for it for days.

Answer (score 1):

then add one more property in #sidebar

```
#sidebar {
width:400px;
height:550px;
padding:10px;
float:left;
text-transform:uppercase;
position:fixed;
left:835px;
overflow:scroll-x;
}
```

Comment: yeah that doesn't work its a fixed positioned div it will require more than CSS I am positive of that.

Answer (score 0):

That example site is using more than just css to generate that effect.  It is also using a MooTools plugin: ScrollSpy.  http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy

View the source at  http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/ to see the scripting and the full css.