# Fix a div using position:fixed for a particular direction

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to fix a div using `position:fixed` in only top to bottom direction; i.e when I scroll from left to right the div should not be fixed. It should behave as a absolute positioned element. It should be fixed only when I scroll from top to bottom. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't think it's possible with purely CSS, but check [this jQuery solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067603/fixed-position-div-vertical-only)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, because it's not supposed to be.

The action of "scrolling" may be very different from a browser to an other... from a device to an other... So it's not predictable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure good solution then, I would recommend you use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
If you will implement it using CSS then it may not be smooth.